# How to compare a column with a cell id instead of value using google sheets conditional formatting option?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I want to change the background color of a particular cell in a column if the value of that cell is greater than one cell in another column.

For example, the column that I want to compare all cells is `Y` and the cell that should be compared with is `AA5`

Right now I am manually comparing by adding the value of `AA5` to the greater than format rule in google sheets conditional formatting.

I tried using `=IF($Y:$Y>$AA5)` and `=$Y:$Y<$AA5` in the custom formula but didn't work.

Need help on this.

[image: this is how I tried, please refer the screenshot]

Comment: `=IF(Y1>AA$5, 1)` and `=Y1>AA$5` should work too

Comment: that worked, can you tell me how to add the background color to a row if the value in y column and z column is greather than AA5 for Y value and AA7 for Z value, I tried `=AND($Y:$Y>AA5,$Z:$Z>AA8)` this but didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- apply to range **`Y1:Y`**
- select **`Greater than`**
- custom formula: **`=AA$5`**

[image]

Comment: that worked, can you tell me how to add the background color to a row if the value in y column and z column is greather than AA5 for Y value and AA7 for Z value, I tried `=AND($Y:$Y>AA5,$Z:$Z>AA8)` this but didn't work.

Comment: @playero thanks, but I want the full row to be colored only if `Y` value is greater than `AA5` and `Z` is greater than AA8 in the same row. I mean it should satisfy both conditions.
can you please give me that rule?

Comment: @chijumelveettil `=AND(IF($Y1>$AA$5,1),IF($Z1>$AA$8,1))` https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PS2w.png

Comment: superb, thanks! one issue is that blank cells are also considered as greater than value, please check this screenshot, https://snag.gy/M9jhTk.jpg

Comment: is there a way to exclude blank columns?

Comment: @chijumelveettil try: `=AND(IF($Y1>$AA$5,1),IF($Z1>$AA$8,1),IF(y1=NOT(ISNUMBER($y1)),1))` https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjy7H.png

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, I appreciate the help.